# when I try to build my react native expo project using eas build command. it shows the following error. how to solve it?

Tags: react-native, expo, build.gradle

[stderr]
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
707
[stderr]

- What went wrong:
  708
  [stderr]
  Execution failed for task ':expo-splash-screen:compileReleaseKotlin'.
  709
  [stderr]

> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
> 710
> [stderr]
> Compilation error. See log for more details
> 711
> [stderr]

- Try:
  712
  [stderr]

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> 713
> [stderr]
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> 714
> [stderr]
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> 715
> [stderr]

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
  716
  [stderr]
  BUILD FAILED in 5m 43s
  717
  Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.
  718
  You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.
  719
  See https://docs.gradle.org/8.0.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
  720
  248 actionable tasks: 248 executed
  721
  Error: Gradle build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run gradlew" phase for more information.

Comment: you can try to [prebuilding](https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/prebuild/) your app, reinstalling all dependencies and also use [expo doctor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/expo-doctor) to fix wrong dependencies versions

Comment: Reinstalling of all dependencies solved my app building problem. Thanks